# Limiting the number of map overlays depending on the zoom level

Tags: android

I have over 5000 overlay items that I'd like to potentially display on my map.

What I need is a way of adding only the ones that are relevant to the current location and zoom level. And obviously adding or removing items as the map area or zoom changes.

Is there any way of handling this without attempting to add them all at once?

Comment: Are you creating your own `Overlay` or using `ItemizedOverlay` to display all these items?

Answer (score 0):

Well...im adding my overlays using the draw() method. If you are also using this method to add your overlays then you can simply cover any overlay in this method with an if statement having the condition:
`mapView.getZoomLevel > yourMinimumLevel`. Since draw() is called each time the map is dragged or zoomed, it will remove your overlay if the zoom level condition is not satisfied..
Hope this helps.. :)